# How to upload a file with Prism library in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, file-upload, prism

I have an WPF application written on the top of [Prism Library](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)

I want to allow the user to upload a profile-picture from their profile. On their edit profile view, I added the following XAML code

```
<Grid Grid.Row="10"
      Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox MinWidth="150" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
    <Button Content="Browse" Command="{Binding Path=UploadImage}"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0 0 5 0"></Button>
</Grid>
```

The `UploadImage` command will need to display a dialog to browse the user's PC for the pictures.

Using Prims and the MVVM, how can I correctly display a file-browser? Then how can I upload the selected file into the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to display file open dialog in WPF and MVVM is to use a service, which represents a open file dialog. You should inject this service into your ViewModel, using usual IoC method in the Prism.

This service INTERFACE should not depend on any particular ui method (usually it is very easy to implement it in the command line test or unit test mock).

The IMPLEMENTATION of the service should be in the project which depends on WPF, and this implementation should then call OpenFileDialog to open file.

Your button command should call the instance of the service, passed to the ViewModel, and open the dialog.

There are many implementations of this idea, here's a simple one:

```
public interface IOpenFileService
{
/// <summary>
/// Open  file
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if file selected</returns>
bool? OpenFile();

/// <summary>
/// Full names of the selected files
/// </summary>
string[] FileNames { get; }
}

public class OpenFileService: IOpenFileService
{
    OpenFileDialog _openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    string[] _selectedFileNames;

    public bool? OpenFile()
    {
        _openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        var ofd = _openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (ofd.HasValue && ofd.Value)
        {
            _selectedFileNames = _openFileDialog.FileNames; 
        }
        return ofd;
    }

    public string[] FileNames
    {
        get { return _selectedFileNames ; }
    }
}
```

So you register the implementation of the service, and your ViewModel receives the implementation in the constructor:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
     public SomeViewModel(IFileOpenService fileOpen)
     {
         this._fileOpen = fileOpen; 
     }

     public void FileOpenCommandExecute
     {
         if (this._fileOpen.OpenFile())
         {
             var selectedFiles = this._fileOpen.FileNames;
             // .. do something with the selected files...
         }
     }
}
```

There are other implementations, which support many other dialog types, so you should look for them too, but this is a basic idea.

HTH, Tom